# spock mock argument matching failure

Tags: testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I have written a Spock test mocking the jersey environment (app is DropWizard). In my expectations (then block), the test fails stating there are too few invocations. Yet, my sysout in the class under test shows that the resource being registered has the same values as those in the expected resource. I must be missing something quite obvious, but cannot see it.

Here is the resource definition:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public final class ForecastResource {
    final String defaultState
    final String defaultCity
    final String defaultApiKeyLocation
    final AtomicLong counter

    private final WundergroundClient wundergroundClient

    public ForecastResource(final String defaultState, final String defaultCity, final String defaultApiKeyLocation) {
        this(defaultState, defaultCity, defaultApiKeyLocation, new WundergroundClient())
    }

    public ForecastResource(final String defaultState, final String defaultCity, final String defaultApiKeyLocation, final WundergroundClient wundergroundClient) {
        this.defaultState = defaultState
        this.defaultCity = defaultCity
        this.defaultApiKeyLocation = defaultApiKeyLocation
        this.wundergroundClient = wundergroundClient
        this.counter = new AtomicLong()
    }

...
}
```

Here is the code under test:

```
public void run(ForecastConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    final ForecastResource resource = new ForecastResource(
        configuration.getDefaultState(),
        configuration.getDefaultCity(),
        configuration.getDefaultApiKeyLocation()
    )

    final TemplateHealthCheck healthCheck =
        new TemplateHealthCheck(configuration.getDefaultCity())


    environment.healthChecks().register("template", healthCheck)
    println "registering ${resource.toString()}"
    environment.jersey().register(resource)
}
```

And, here is my test code:

```
def "validate run registers the resource"() {

    given: "environment has mock jersey and health check implementations"
    def mockJerseyEnvironment = Mock(JerseyEnvironment)
    def mockHealthCheckRegistry = Mock(HealthCheckRegistry)
    def mockEnvironment = Mock(Environment)
    mockEnvironment.healthChecks() >> mockHealthCheckRegistry
    mockEnvironment.jersey() >> mockJerseyEnvironment

    and: "a configuration for portland WA"
    ForecastConfiguration configuration = new ForecastConfiguration(defaultState: "WA", defaultCity: "Portland", defaultApiKeyLocation: '/forecast/serviceadapter/test-wunderground.properties')

    and: "a resource expected to be registered"
    ForecastResource expectedResource = new ForecastResource("WA", "Portland", '/forecast/serviceadapter/test-wunderground.properties')

    and: "a health check expected to be registered"
    TemplateHealthCheck expectedHealthCheck = new TemplateHealthCheck("Portland")

    when: "run is called"
    new ForecastApplication().run(configuration, mockEnvironment)

    then: "expect resource and health check to be registered"
    1 * mockJerseyEnvironment.register(expectedResource)
    1 * mockHealthCheckRegistry.register("template", expectedHealthCheck)
}
```

Finally, here are the results from the sysout followed by the stack trace:

```
registered :registering forecast.resources.ForecastResource(WA, Portland, /forecast/serviceadapter/test-wunderground.properties, 0)

Too few invocations for:

1 * mockJerseyEnvironment.register(expectedResource)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * mockJerseyEnvironment.register(forecast.resources.ForecastResource(WA, Portland, /forecast/serviceadapter/test-wunderground.properties, 0))


    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:76)
    at forecast.ForecastApplicationSpec.validate run registers the resource(ForecastApplicationSpec.groovy:32)
```

Comment: Most likely `ForecastResource` doesn't implement `Object#equals`, or doesn't implement it the way you think it does.

Comment: Hi Peter - Thanks. I had included the counter - an instance of AtomicLong - as a property. Once I converted that to a field all was well. If you motivated to put that in an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: @BillTurner you can add an answer on your own and accept it yourself. It is a common thing in stack overflow.